# Arduino BLE Raspberry reading data

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, bluetooth-lowenergy

Trying to send data over BLE from Redbear Blend Micro Arduino board to a Raspberry Pi (Raspian), bluez 5.37.

I'm using the [nRF8001 HelloWorld.ino sketch](https://github.com/RedBearLab/nRF8001/blob/master/examples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.ino).

I can receive "Hello World" if running the Redbear BLE controller app on Android.

From the RPI I can use gatttool and connect to the Blend Micro.

Questions:

1. How can I find out what the the different handles represents?
2. How can I read "hello world" from gatttool?

My end purpose is to read data from my dht11 humidity sensor and display on a dashboard using d3js over websockets. I got the chain to work fine with serial usb so "only" need to get the bluetooth going. For Python code I'm trying to go as vanilla as possible using pexpect and gatttool.

Thanks in advance.

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo gatttool -b EC:EA:FA:D8:F9:77 -t random -I
[EC:EA:FA:D8:F9:77][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to EC:EA:FA:D8:F9:77
Connection successful
[EC:EA:FA:D8:F9:77][LE]> primary
attr handle: 0x0001, end grp handle: 0x0007 uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0008, end grp handle: 0x000b uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x000c, end grp handle: 0x0011 uuid: 713d0000-503e-4c75-ba94-3148f18d941e
attr handle: 0x0012, end grp handle: 0xffff uuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[EC:EA:FA:D8:F9:77][LE]> char-desc
handle: 0x0001, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0002, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0003, uuid: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0004, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0005, uuid: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0006, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0007, uuid: 00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0008, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0009, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000a, uuid: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000b, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000c, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000d, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000e, uuid: 713d0003-503e-4c75-ba94-3148f18d941e
handle: 0x000f, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0010, uuid: 713d0002-503e-4c75-ba94-3148f18d941e
handle: 0x0011, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0012, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0013, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0014, uuid: 00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`

Answer (score 0):

Able to read the device name by reading handle 3.
char-read-hand 0x00003

And also request for data from handle 11.
char-write-req 0x0011 0100

Still trying to figure out what all the handles represent.